# How to flip picture at an angle in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do i flip the top starship ( the darker one) at a 45 degree angle so it's facing the same way as the lighter ship? I want to flip because I want the sun reflection to be on the same side (upper right)

[image: flip]

Answer (score 3):

There's no way you will be able to match the perspective of the two ships. They are at exact opposite angles and even if you do rotate and flip the dark ship to get the ships going the same direction, the ship will be upside down and in the reverse perspective.

In addition, the lighting *moves with the image*. There's no way to transform a flat two dimensional object and have the lighting miraculously know to stay in the same place/direction. If you rotate or flip that dark ship to match the angle of the grey ship, then light will then be from the bottom left (and the ship upside down and the perspective backwards).

Flat, non-3D, images just don't work the way you want.